# Updating variable automatically whenever content of a specific HTML node changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create a variable which should always have the value of the text in a paragraph, but it should also update the variable if the text in the paragraph changes? Is this possible in jQuery or Javascript?

I want to define the variable just once and then never have to update it manually again.

For example if I have the variable `valuePAdd`:

```
var valuePAdd = $("p").text() + " <--text of paragraph";
```

Now if I change the text in the paragraph, I would have to manually do this again:

```
valuePAdd = $("p").text() + " <--text of paragraph"
```

And that's what I want to avoid, so that it will automatically do the update I had to write out in the second example.

Comment: You can do this with DOM observers, but the best way is to store the variable pointing to the paragraph itself and call `.text()` when you need it.

Comment: Just read the text in the paragraph when you need it, no need to store in a variable.

Comment: Ok, I've tried @Scott solution of pointing to the paragraph in a variable and that's all I needed. Thank you! Is there a way to kind of "close" a question on stackoverflow, because I doubt other people will find this overly useful.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (and most idiomatic jQuery) is to not use a variable to hold the text content but instead get the paragraph's text content each time it's used. If the situation calls for a variable, store the jQuery object referencing the paragraph (or whichever element that is holding the text).

```
var $p = $("p#Watched");
// …
$p.text();
// …
$p.text();
```

If the text is stored in an object property, you can create a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), which nicely hides the paragraph as an implementation detail:

```
let obj = {
    $p: $('p#Watched'),
    get valuePAdd() {
        return this.$p.text();
    }
};
```

If that doesn't meet requirements, then there's one option remaining. Updating anything automatically when DOM nodes change means using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). You [create an observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) with a callback function that gets invoked when a mutation happens. You then tell the observer what node to [observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe), along with what types of mutations.

To view all text updates, you'll need to observe the `childList` (for text & element node insertions) and `characterData` (for changes to text node content) mutation types. You can exclude the `attributes` mutation type. You must set the `subtree` option, so that changes to descendants of the paragraph element will be observed.

The callback itself will receive a list of mutations, as well as the observer.

jQuery doesn't have any built-in support for mutation observers, so the sample below doesn't make use of it (though you certainly could use jQuery for a few things, replacing `document.getElementById` or `Node.innerText`).

```js
const watched = document.getElementById('Watched');
var valuePAdd = watched.innerText;

console.log(`valuePAdd: ${valuePAdd}`);

/* Using MutationObserver */
function watch(mutationsList, observer) {
    valuePAdd = watched.innerText;
    console.log(`mutation type: ${mutationsList[0].type};\n\ttarget: ${mutationsList[0].target.id};\n\tvaluePAdd: '${valuePAdd}'`);
}

var config = { childList: true, characterData: true, attributes: false, subtree: true },
    observer = new MutationObserver(watch);
observer.observe(watched, config);

/* Change the text. */
watched.childNodes[0].nodeValue = '1 new ';
setTimeout(function () {
    // could also use textContent
    watched.children[0].innerText = ' content 2';
    setTimeout(function () {
        watched.innerText = '3 foo baz';
        watched.innerText = '4 foo bar';
        watched.innerText = '5 Foo bar.';
    }, 500);
}, 500);
```

```html
<p id="Watched">initial <span id="Child">text</span></p>
```

`MutationObserver`s replaced the deprecated `MutationEvent`s, which had worse performance and less browser support. `MutationEvents` can be used more directly by jQuery (`$('p').on('DOMSubtreeModified', …)`), but this doesn't actually provide a benefit beyond the very minor one of calling just one framework (as you don't have code based on the DOM directly).

For comparison, consider the following `MutationEvent` based implementation, which shows the potential for worse performance due to being triggered more often. Note that the callback gets called more times, including when text is removed.

```js
const watched = document.getElementById('Watched');
var valuePAdd = watched.innerText;

console.log(`valuePAdd: ${valuePAdd}`);

/* Using MutationEvent */
function watch(evt) {
    valuePAdd = watched.innerText;
    console.log(`type: ${evt.type};\n\ttarget: ${evt.target.id};\n\tvaluePAdd: '${valuePAdd}'`);
}
watched.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', watch);

/* Change the text. */
watched.childNodes[0].nodeValue = '1 new ';
setTimeout(function () {
    // could also use textContent
    watched.children[0].innerText = ' content 2';
    setTimeout(function () {
        watched.innerText = '3 foo baz';
        watched.innerText = '4 foo bar';
        watched.innerText = '5 Foo bar.';
    }, 500);
}, 500);
```

```html
<p id="Watched">initial <span id="Child">text</span></p>
```